# A question on primitive rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Is there any characterization for the left primitive rings which are left duo ?  Clearly division rings satisfy this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class of rings in the question is exactly the class of Division rings. Here is another proof based on the characterization of primitive rings.

**Proof.** Since you have asked about primitive rings I can assume that you are familiar with the **Jacobson's Density Theorem**. Therefore $R$ can be regarded as a dense subring of linear transformations of a vector space $V$ over a division ring $D$. It is enough to show that $\mbox{dim}_D V = 1$ (since then $R$ would be equal to $D$) . Suppose not and consider two linearly independent vectors $u,v \in V$. By density there are $f,h \in R$ such that $f(u) = u , f(v) = 0$ and $h(u) = u , h(v) = u$. Now Take $I$ to be the left ideal generated by $f$ in $R$. We show that $fh \not \in I$ (which is a contradiction since by assumptions any left ideal of $R$ is two-sided):

If $fh \in I$ then there exists $g \in R$ such that $fh = gf$. Hence $u = fh(v) = gf(v) =  g(0) = 0$ a contradiction !

Comment: I accept this solution since the argument works even if $R$ assumed to be a right duo ring. 

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I'm afraid these rings aren't very interesting: a left primitive ring $R$ is left duo if and only if it is a division ring.

For the nontrivial direction, suppose $R$ is left duo.  Fix a faithful simple left $R$-module, which up to isomorphism is of the form $R/M$ for a maximal left ideal $M$.  As $R$ is left duo, $M$ is in fact a two-sided ideal.  But for $R/M$ to be simple, this means that $M = 0$. Thus $M = 0$ is a maximal (left) ideal, and $R$ is a division ring.

Comment: @Manny Reyes: Thanks for your celever solution.  But I accepted chatish's solution since his argument works even if we assume that $R$ is a right duo ring (instead of left duo ring). 